# Condiciones OR en javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio muy simple para saber si un hombre o una mujer son candidatos para la jubilizacion, esto es con una seria de variables como el sexo, la edad, los años trabajando y las semanas cotizadas, bien, si alguna de estas fallas debes devolver que no es candidato y la razon de esto, para el hombre tenemos que debe ser mayor de 60 años y la mujer mayor de 55 años, ambos deber tener mas de 25 años trabajando y ambos deben tener mas de 800 semanas cotizadas, este es el codigo que llevo se que tengo que mejorarlo pero aun no puedo ver los demas errores porque no puedo salir del primer condicional, por ejemplo, al poner que es Hombre  y que su edad es 59 no me salta que 'No es jubilable', me podrian indicar en qué me estoy equivocando por favor

```js
let usuarioSexo = prompt("Indique si es Mujer u Hombre"), usuarioEdad = prompt("Indique su edad"), usuarioTiempo = prompt("Indique los años trabajando"), usuarioSemanas = prompt("Indique las semanas cotizadas"), pointer = false, pointer2 = false;
    
document.write(`<br><br>Su sexo es: ${usuarioSexo} <br>
    Edad: ${usuarioEdad} <br>
    Años trabajando: ${usuarioTiempo}<br>
    Semanas Cotizadas: ${usuarioSemanas}<br>`);
    
usuarioSexo = usuarioSexo.toLowerCase();
    
if (usuarioSexo == "hombre" || "h" && usuarioEdad >= 60 || (usuarioSexo == "mujer" || "m" && usuarioEdad >= 55)) {
    pointer = true;
}
else {
    document.write("<br> No es jubilable, su edad es menor");
}
    
/* 
if (pointer == true && usuarioTiempo >= 25) {
    pointer2 = true;
}
else {
    document.write(`<br> Usted no es jubilable, tiene menos de 25 años trabajando`);
}
    
if (pointer2 == true && self, usuarioSemanas >= 800) {
    document.write(`<br> Felicitaciones, usted es jubilable`);
}
else {
    document.write(`<br> Usted no es jubilable, tiene menos de 800 semanas cotizadas`);
} */
```

Comment: Están incompletas tus evaluaciones, debe ser: `variable === algo || variable === otro`, es decir debes colocar de nuevo a la variable por cada condición a verificar

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue sin funcionar me di cuenta de otro error y es que el `prompt()` agarra valores `strings` asi que usé `Number(usuarioEdad)` para conventirlo en un numero y luego ejecutar los condicionales pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Lo que mencioné solo es parte de las observaciones, te sugiero edites explicando que comportamiento tiene ahora tu código

Answer (score 4):

Estas usando mal la operación OR, siempre debe ir entre operaciones booleanas.

Esto está mal:

```
 usuarioSexo == "hombre" || "h"
```

Debe ser así:

```
usuarioSexo == "hombre" || usuarioSexo == "h"
```

Otro tema es el orden de ejecución de las operaciones booleanas, los AND se van a ejecutar antes que las OR, de manera que falta poner el primer OR entre paréntesis, igual que hiciste con el segundo OR. Así:

```
if ( ((usuarioSexo == "hombre" || usuarioSexo ==  "h") && usuarioEdad >= 60 ) || ( (usuarioSexo == "mujer" || usuarioSexo == "m") && usuarioEdad >= 55)) {
    pointer = true;
}
else {
    document.write("<br> No es jubilable, su edad es menor");
}
```

Comment: Gracias! si tiene razon, ahora si funciona cuando coloco 'h' es decir sexo:h edad:59, pero cuando coloco 'hombre' no funciona, estoy comparando mal las strings?

Comment: Te lo comento en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que asignes las condiciones a variables, y luego las metas en el `if` así estará más ordenador. Por ejemplo:

```js
const esHombre = [ 'hombre', 'h' ].includes(usuarioSexo.toLowerCase());
const esMujer = [ 'mujer', 'm' ].includes(usuarioSexo.toLowerCase());
const mayorDe60 = usuarioEdad >= 60;
const mayorDe55 = usuarioEdad >= 55;
const masDe25Anios = usuarioTiempo >= 25;
const masDe800Semanas = usuarioSemanas >= 800;
```

Luego los condicionales tienen mucho sentido cuando los lees:

```js
if ((esHombre && mayorDe60) || (esMujer && mayorDe55))
```

Con algunos cambios más, podría quedarte así (he quitado toda la lógica del DOM para que pueda ser ejecutable aquí):

```js
let usuarioSexo = prompt("Indique si es Mujer u Hombre").toLowerCase();
const usuarioEdad = parseInt(prompt("Indique su edad"), 10);
const usuarioTiempo = parseInt(prompt("Indique los años trabajando"), 10);
const usuarioSemanas = parseInt(prompt("Indique las semanas cotizadas"), 10);

console.log(`Sexo: ${usuarioSexo}, edad: ${usuarioEdad}, trabajando: ${usuarioTiempo}, cotizadas: ${usuarioSemanas}`);

const esHombre = [ 'hombre', 'h' ].includes(usuarioSexo.toLowerCase());
const esMujer = [ 'mujer', 'm' ].includes(usuarioSexo.toLowerCase());
const mayorDe60 = usuarioEdad >= 60;
const mayorDe55 = usuarioEdad >= 55;
const masDe25Anios = usuarioTiempo >= 25;
const masDe800Semanas = usuarioSemanas >= 800;
    
if ((esHombre && mayorDe60) || (esMujer && mayorDe55)) {
  if (masDe25Anios) {
    if (masDe800Semanas) {
      console.log('Felicitaciones, usted es jubilable');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Usted no es jubilable, tiene menos de 800 semanas cotizadas');
    }
  }
  else {
      console.log('Usted no es jubilable, tiene menos de 25 años trabajando');
  }
}
else {
    console.log('No es jubilable');
}
```

Comment: Vaya! tu codigo esta muy bien, no lo hubiese pensado de esta manera, muchas gracias!